# Why await an async function directly not work without assigning it to a Task variable

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Typically, I do the following

```
public static async Task dosth()
{
    List<Task> job = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        job.Add(sleep());
    }
    Task.WhenAll(job.ToArray());
}

static async Task sleep()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Finish new");
}
```

It works smoothly, no problem. But when I do a review on my own code (trying using other syntax to do the same job), I suddenly figure out the following two are different.

```
public static async Task dosthA()
{
    //This will be working synchronously, take 3 seconds.
    await sleep();
    await sleep();
    await sleep();

    //This will be working asynchronously, take 1 second only.
    Task A = sleep();
    Task B = sleep();
    Task C = sleep();
    await A;
    await B;
    await C;
}
```

Why assigning the async function to a new variable make difference? I originally think they are the same.

**Update**

Why it is confusing me is, actually in [Microsoft doc on Async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index),
They stated the following in their code.

```
// Calls to TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync  
Task<int> returnedTaskTResult = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();  
int intResult = await returnedTaskTResult;  
// or, in a single statement  
int intResult = await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
```

They are actually different, why they use `//or , in a single statement`, just because it makes no different in their own example?

Comment: A B and C all execute at the same time. when awaited they would have already completed.

Comment: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you are returning a running `Task` when you call `Sleep()` even when you're assigning to a variable.

The confusion is that the `Task` does not begin if you assign it to a variable (`A`, `B`, or `C`) until you call `await A;` **but that's not true**.  As soon as you assign `sleep();` to `A`, `sleep()` was called; therefore the `Task` in the `sleep()` method is running. Assigning it to a variable or not the `Task` begins when you call the method; because in the method you start the `Task`.

Knowing this; when you call:

```
await A;
await B;
await C;
```

A, B, and C, have already starting simultaneously... After awaiting A it is most likely B, and C have also completed or are milliseconds from completing.

There are situations where you can reference a `Task` that hasn't started yet but you would have to purposely return a non-running `Task` to do that.

To answer the edit to your question also.

`Task`s have a method called `GetAwaiter()` which returns a `TaskAwaiter`. In C# when you write `var task = sleep();` then you're assigning the actual `Task` to the task variable.  All the same when you write `await sleep();` the compiler does some cool stuff and it actually calls the `Task.GetAwaiter()` method; which is subscribed to.  The `Task` will run and when it is complete the `TaskAwaiter` fires the continuation action.  This can't be explained in a simple answer but to know the outer logic helps.

Among other things the `TaskAwaiter` implements `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` which in turn implements `INotifyCompletion`.  Both have one method each, `OnCompleted(Action)` and `UnsafeOnCompleted(Action)`  (you can guess which is which by naming convention).

Another thing to note is that `Task.GetAwaiter()` returns a `TaskAwaiter` but `Task<TResult>.GetAwaiter()` returns a `TaskAwaiter<TResult>`.   There's not a strong difference in the two but there is a difference in the `GetResult()` method of the two tasks; which is what's called while marshalling back to the proper threading context.  The `TaskAwaiter.GetResult()` returns void and the `TaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()` returns `TResult`.

I feel like if I push further into this I'll have to write pages to explain it all in detail... Hopefully just explaining your question and pulling the curtain back a little bit will shed enough light to help you both understand and dig deeper if you're more curious.

Ok, so based on the comment below I want to describe my answer a little bit further.

I'll start this simple; let's just make a `Task`; one that isn't running, and look at it first.

```
public Task GetTask()
{
    var task = new Task(() => { /*some work to be done*/ });
    //Now we have a reference to a non-running task.
    return task;
}
```

We can now call code like:

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    await GetTask();
}
```

… but we'll be waiting forever; until the application ends, because the `Task` was never started.  However; we could do something like this:

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    var task = GetTask();
    task.Start();
    await task;
}
```

… and it will await the running `Task` and continue once the `Task` is complete.

Knowing this you can make as many calls to `GetTask()` as you like and you'll only be referencing `Task`s that have not started.

In your code it's just the opposite, which is fine, as this is the most used way.  I encourage you to make sure your method names notify the user of how you're returning the `Task`.  If the `Task` is already running the most common convention is the end the method name with `Async`.  Here's another example doing it with a running `Task` for clarity.

```
public Task DoTaskAsync()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => { /*some work to be done*/ });
    //Now we have a reference to a task that's already running.
    return task;
}
```

And now we will most likely call this method like:

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    await DoTaskAsync();
}
```

However; note that if we simply want to reference the `Task` just like we did earlier, we can, the only difference is this `Task` is running where the one prior was not.  So this code is valid.

```
public async void DoWork()
{
    var task = DoTaskAsync();
    await task;
}
```

The big take away is how C# handles the async / await keywords.  `async` tells the compiler that the method is going to become a continuation of a `Task`.  In short; the compiler knows to look for all `await` calls and put the rest of the method in a continuation.

The `await` keyword tells the compiler to call the `Task.GetAwaiter()` method on the `Task` ( and basically subscribe to the `INotifyCompletion` and `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`) to signal the continuation in the method.

---

And this I wanted to add just incase you weren't aware.  If you do have more than one task that you want to await but would rather await one task as if they were all one then you can do that with `Task.WhenAll()` So instead of:

```
var taskA = DoTaskAsync();
var taskB = DoTaskAsync();
var taskC = DoTaskAsync();

await taskA;
await taskB;
await taskC;
```

You could write it a little cleaner like so:

```
var taskA = DoTaskAsync(); 
var taskB = DoTaskAsync(); 
var taskC = DoTaskAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);
```

And there are more ways of doing this sort of thing built in; just explore it.

Comment: I see. Let me make it simple, see if I am saying wrong. As when I write `await sleep()`, I actually get a new `TaskAwaiter` and `await` it at the same moment, therefore block the thread. Am I right?

Comment: yeah you're still saying it wrong.  Let me update my answer at the very bottom for just a little bit more clarification.  I think you're on the right path though.

Comment: No, I think you're confusing yourself again.  In the MS example the task is already running.. it's as if they wrote ```return Task.Run(() => … );``` in their method.  Remember what I said in the answer; if you don't use the ```await``` keyword then you just get the result of the method; which in this case is a running ```Task```.  If you do use the ```await``` keyword then you must be referencing a ```Task``` (and it just so happens the result of that method call is a ```Task``` that is running.)

Comment: Therefore when you use ```await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();``` you're subscribing to the completion of the ```Task``` but when you use ```var task = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();``` (notice there's no await) you're not subscribing to the completion but referencing the task itself.  You can subscribe to the completion of any task so how you reference it doesn't matter.  ```await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();``` is no different than ```var task = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();    await task;```

Comment: May be like this... how should I convert my `sleep()`, to make three `await sleep()` can work asynchronously. Or simply can't.

Comment: The way you have it is correct and the way it is working is correct.  I would change the name of the method to ```sleepAsync()``` but it is working like it's supposed to.  If you want to await them in order then call them in order awaited like you did await sleep(), await sleep(), await sleep().  If you want them all to run simultaneously and want to await to make sure they are all done then do it like you have where you referenced A, B, and C and then called await A, await B, await C.